# How should I call a function in java script by Python

Tags: java, python

I am totally new to code.

I have a java code to control the temperature, moving position, and force of a probe in a device. Functions have all been created.
In order to call them in Python, for example, I will put `ser.write(b'p\n')` for turning on top heaters.
These are some command explanations:

- h - home (move fully down to limit switch, then up to HOMEPOSITION)
- P + BYTE + BYTE - goto position micrometers [0-65535]
- t - tare (zero load cell)
- g + BYTE + BYTE - load target, grams [0-65535]
- j + BYTE - temp  setpoint, deg C [0-255]
- p - top heaters on

Below is the input of the command:

```java
void manageCommand() {

    int input = Serial.read();
    buffer[commandSize++] = input;
    
    if((input == 13) || (input == 10) && commandSize > 0 && buffer[0] != 'g' && buffer[0] != 'P') {
        commandSize--; // ignore newline
        parseCommand();
        commandSize = 0; 
    } 
    else if ((buffer[0]=='g' || buffer[0] == 'P') && commandSize == 3) { // commands with DWORD values
        parseCommand();
        commandSize = 0;
    }
    else if ((input == 13 || input == 10) && commandSize == 1)  commandSize = 0; // ignore solitary newlines

    lastHostHeartBeat = time;
    
}
```

This is for P, moving to specific position:

```
else if (buffer[0] == 'P') {
    int a = buffer[1];
    int b = buffer[2]; 
    double tp = ((long) word(b,a));
    tp /= 1000; // convert to mm
    if (tp > MAXPOSITION) targetpos = MAXPOSITION;
    else if (tp < 0) tp = 0;
    gotoposition(tp);
}
```

My question is what I should put in `ser.write(b'\n')` for P if I want to go to position 15mm. I don't understand what "+" is for, maybe P+0+15? or P,0,15 or just space?

Comment: `java` is not same with `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For position 15mm you need to pass in 15000 due to `tp /= 1000; // convert to mm`, the two bytes are `00111010 10011000`. You should pass `b'P\x3a\x98\n'`. Note that `0000000000001111` (binary) is `3a98` (hexadecimal).

The position requires two bytes in order to represent all possible values. Look at the range: `0-65535`. Note that a byte is eight bits, and two bytes are 16 bits. You can represent 2^16 = 65536 different values with 16 bits. The plus signs don't go in the bytes that you send to the controller, they merely indicate that the command format for moving the probe is a `P` followed by two bytes indicating a position between 0 and 65535.